# How do I call an angular function from within an angular function?

Tags: angularjs

I have written an angular function that works fine. Now, I want to write another angular function that calls the first function. How can I do this?

```
app.controller("AppCtrl",function($scope,$location,$http,$compile,$rootScope){
    $scope.func1 = function(param1,param2){
        ... // function body
    };
    $scope.func2 = function(param3) {
        var value = "someValue";
        $scope.func1(value,param3);
    };
});
```

Unfortunately `func2()` doesn't work, even though `fucn1()` works if I call it directly (e.g., `<div ng-click="func1(val1,val2)">Click Here</div>`. Why?

UPDATE:

It's because I'm doing the following:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-click="func2('{{item.value}}') ng-repeat="item in items">Item</li>
</ul>
```

For some reason `{{item.value}}` is not being compiled in the `ng-repeat`. I can inspect the HTML and see that the values are there, but the `ng-click` doesn't do anything. However, if I manually enter a value for the parameter in `func2`, then it works. So, now my questions is: How do I compile items in an ng-repeat?

Comment: There should be no problem with this.  What behaviour or error are you receiving.

Comment: Explain "doesn't work".

Comment: "value" is undefined at `func2`

Comment: Where are you expecting `value` to come from?

Comment: @DavinTryon I have updated the question. For some reason the items in my ng-repeat are not being compiled.

Comment: create a demo in plunker or jsfiddle.net that replicates problem. What you have displayed is too fragmented to see what issue could be

Comment: also remove expression braces around `item.value` should be `ng-click="func2(item.value)"` since function is evaluated within angular scope

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your example here: http://jsfiddle.net/CsffM/

The problem is that you are using brackets in your expression,
Insted, do this:

```
<li ng-click="func2(item.value)" ng-repeat="item in items">Item</li>
```

I hope I have helped!